# Java programming, decimals numbers

Tags: java, bluej

This is a compound interest calculator, everything works fine excepts that i can't figured how to get my answer to have just 2 decimals, not a long number as right now. Please take a look at the codes and suggest if anything i should correct. Thank you very much.

```
class InvestmentProject{
public double CompoundInterest(double InitialDeposit, double YearlyContribution, double InterestRate, int PeriodsInYr) {

double RateInDecimal = InterestRate/100;
double Value = YearlyContribution/RateInDecimal - YearlyContribution/(RateInDecimal * Math.pow(1 + RateInDecimal, PeriodsInYr));
return (InitialDeposit + Value) * Math.pow(1 + RateInDecimal, PeriodsInYr);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never use floats or doubles when doing financial calculations, and particularly comparisons, in Java. use BigDecimal instead. [Here is an article that explains why](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-01-04-practical-floating-point.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.round(result*100)/100;`

There's a similar question here ( [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java) ) that outlines more ways of doing rounding in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the decimalFormat Class

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;  

public class Java0605
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        DecimalFormat output = new DecimalFormat("00000");
        System.out.println(output.format(1));
        System.out.println(output.format(12));
        System.out.println(output.format(123));
        System.out.println(output.format(1234));
        System.out.println(output.format(12345));
        System.out.println(output.format(123456));
        System.out.println(output.format(1234567));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```